# Perl - Process string with IDs and corresponding values in quotation marks

Tags: string, perl, hash

I'm working on a Perl project where i have a lot of strings containing ids and corresponding values in quotation marks, seperated by semicolons.

Example: main_id "1234567"; second_id "My_ID"; name "Andreas";

There is a blank behind every ID-name and behind every semicolon.

There are 2 problems I'm dealing with:

Problem 1: What is the fastest way to get the value (without quotation marks) to a specific id? My first try didn't work:

```
$id_list = 'main_id "1234567"; second_id "My_ID"; name "Andreas";';
$wanted_id = 'second_id';
($value = $id_list) =~ s/.*$wanted_id\w"([^"])";.*/$1/;
```

Problem 2: What is the fastest way to turn this string id into a hash for a specific id, that looks like this:

String: main_id "1234567"; second_id "My_ID"; name "Andreas";

Hash for "second_id":

hash{My_ID} = {main_id => 1234567, second_id => My_ID, name => Andreas}

What I tried:

```
$id_list = 'main_id "1234567"; second_id "My_ID"; name "Andreas";';
$wanted_id = 'second_id';
%final_id_hash;
%hash;
my @ids = split ";", $id_list;
foreach my $id (@ids) {
   my ($a,$b)= split " ", $id;
    $b =~ s/"//g;
    $hash{$a} = $b;
}    
$final_hash{$hash{$wanted_id}}= \%hash;
```

This worked, but is there a faster/better solution?

Comment: Solution didn not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1,

```
my %hash = map {
  map { s/ ^" | "$ //xg; $_ } split /\s+/, $_, 2;
}
split /;\s+/, qq{main_id "1234567"; second_id "My_ID"; name "Andreas"};

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%hash;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Text::ParseWords](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aParseWords) module (part of the standard Perl distribution) makes this simple.e.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Text::ParseWords;
use Data::Dumper;

my %final_hash;
my $wanted_id = 'second_id';
my $id_list = 'main_id "1234567"; second_id "My_ID"; name "Andreas";';

my @words = parse_line '[\s;]+', 0, $id_list;
pop @words; # Lose the extra field generated by the ; at the end
my %hash = @words;

$final_hash{$hash{$wanted_id}} = \%hash;

say Dumper \%final_hash;
```